# RecyclerView add dynamically item. NotifyDataChanged doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In this app, i am adding addresses to account and saving them in Realtime database (firebase).I want also to display them in recyclerview but they aren't visible.

Here visualization of my problem : https://youtu.be/OdlZNUQnA-k

The Code should work like this

Addressfragment Contains AddressesRecyclerview

AddAddressfragment for adding new Address
And it goes back to AddressFragment when new Address has been added.

Also when i tried to display all items from one array like for example postcode .It display only last added item. Even on for each loop. Like last item is deleted after adding

I understand that it need something like notifyDataSetChanged() but it doesnt work here

Here is The  code:

AddressFragment:

```
        package com.querto.fragments.address

    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
    import com.querto.R
    import com.querto.adapters.AddressAdapter
    import com.querto.viewmodel.MainActivityViewModel
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_address.view.*


    class AddressFragment : Fragment() {
        private lateinit var mMainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel
        private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
        private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                                  savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            var view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_address, container, false)
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()


           mMainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(requireActivity().application).create(
                MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
            if(mAuth.currentUser==null){
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "To add address please login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                activity?.nav_view?.setCheckedItem(R.id.login)
                activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_in_anim, R.anim.fragment_fade_out_anim, R.anim.fragment_slide_out_anim, R.anim.fragment_fade_in_anim)?.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mMainActivityViewModel.loginFragment)?.commit()

            }

            view.recyclerViewAddress.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            view.recyclerViewAddress.adapter = AddressAdapter(requireContext(), mMainActivityViewModel.list_of_addresses)



            view.add_address_btn.setOnClickListener {
                activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_in_anim, R.anim.fragment_fade_out_anim, R.anim.fragment_slide_out_anim, R.anim.fragment_fade_in_anim)?.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mMainActivityViewModel.addAddressFragment)?.commit()
            }
            return view
        }


    }
```

Adapter:

```
    package com.querto.adapters
    
    import android.app.Application
    import android.content.Context
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
    import com.querto.R
    import com.querto.model.Address
    import com.querto.viewmodel.MainActivityViewModel
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.my_address_row.view.*
    
    class AddressAdapter(contextAdapter: Context, addresses: ArrayList<Address>):
    
    
        RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    
        private var mMainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel
        private val context: Context = contextAdapter
        private val local_addreses : ArrayList<Address> = addresses
        private  var database: DatabaseReference
        private  var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    
        init {
            mMainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(context.applicationContext as Application).create(
                MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        }
    
    
    
        class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val currentTitle = itemView.address_title
            val currentId = itemView.address_id
            val currentStreet = itemView.address_street
            val currentPostcode = itemView.address_postcode
            val currentHouseNumber = itemView.address_number
            val currentAddressCityName = itemView.address_city
        }
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    
            return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_address_row, parent, false))
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.currentTitle.text =  local_addreses[position].name
            holder.currentId.text = (position + 1).toString()
            holder.currentStreet.text =local_addreses[position].street
            holder.currentPostcode.text =local_addreses[position].postcode
            holder.currentHouseNumber.text = local_addreses[position].house_number
            holder.currentAddressCityName.text = local_addreses[position].city_name
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return local_addreses.size
        }
    
        fun addAddress(address: Address){
            mMainActivityViewModel.list_of_addresses.add(address)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
    
        }
    }
```

AddAddress:

```
    package com.querto.fragments.address
    
    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
    import com.querto.R
    import com.querto.adapters.AddressAdapter
    import com.querto.model.Address
    import com.querto.viewmodel.MainActivityViewModel
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_add_address.view.*
    
    class AddAddressFragment : Fragment() {
        private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
        private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
        private lateinit var mMainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
           var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_address, container, false)
    
    
    
            mMainActivityViewModel =
                ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(activity?.application!!)
                    .create(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
    
            view.addAddressButton.setOnClickListener {
    
                val addressName = view.addAddressName.text.toString()
                val addressStreet = view.addAddressStreet.text.toString()
                val addressNumber = view.addAddressHouseNumber.text.toString()
                val addressZipCode = view.addAddressCityZipCode.text.toString()
                val addressCityName = view.addAddressCityName.text.toString()
    
                if(inputCheck(addressName,addressStreet,addressNumber,addressZipCode, addressCityName)){
                    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    
                    addAddress(addressName, addressStreet, addressNumber, addressZipCode, addressCityName)
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Please enter all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            return view
        }
    
        private fun addAddress(addressName: String, addressStreet: String, addressNumber: String,addressZipCode: String, addressCityName: String) {
    
            val address = Address(mAuth.currentUser?.uid, addressName, addressStreet,addressZipCode, addressNumber, addressCityName)
            database.child("addresses").child(database.push().key.toString()).setValue(address).addOnCompleteListener {
                if(it.isSuccessful){
    
                    val addressAdapter= AddressAdapter(requireContext(),  mMainActivityViewModel.list_of_addresses)
                    addressAdapter.addAddress(address)
                    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_in_anim, R.anim.fragment_fade_out_anim, R.anim.fragment_slide_out_anim, R.anim.fragment_fade_in_anim)?.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mMainActivityViewModel.addressFragment)?.commit()
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Added address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Fail at creating address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
    
    
    
        }
    
        private fun inputCheck(addressName: String, addressStreet: String, addressNumber: String,addressZipCode: String, adressCityName: String)=
            addressName.isNotEmpty() && addressStreet.isNotEmpty() && addressNumber.isNotEmpty() && addressZipCode.isNotEmpty() && adressCityName.isNotEmpty() && addressZipCode.length==5
    
    
    
    }
```

MainActivityViewModel:

```kotlin
class MainActivityViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
    val loginFragment = LoginFragment()
    val registerFragment = RegisterFragment()
    val detailsFragment = DetailsFragment()
    val addressFragment = AddressFragment()
    val addAddressFragment = AddAddressFragment()
 
 
    var pizza_names: Array<String> = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.pizza_titles)
    var pizza_desc: Array<String> = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.pizza_desc)
    val pizza_small_price: IntArray = application.resources.getIntArray(R.array.pizza_small_price)
    val pizza_medium_price: IntArray = application.resources.getIntArray(R.array.pizza_medium_price)
    val pizza_big_price: IntArray = application.resources.getIntArray(R.array.pizza_big_price)
    var pizza_img: Array<Int> = arrayOf(R.drawable.napoletana, R.drawable.margherita, R.drawable.estate, R.drawable.pepperone, R.drawable.pancetta, R.drawable.ortolana, R.drawable.marinara, R.drawable.diavola, R.drawable.messicana, R.drawable.quattro_formaggi, R.drawable.sugoza, R.drawable.semola, R.drawable.capriciossa, R.drawable.vulcano, R.drawable.romana, R.drawable.capodanno, R.drawable.primavera, R.drawable.regina, R.drawable.quattro_stagioni, R.drawable.cilento, R.drawable.tirolese, R.drawable.michele, R.drawable.pollo, R.drawable.havana, R.drawable.siciliana, R.drawable.sandra, R.drawable.bari, R.drawable.gringo, R.drawable.angelo, R.drawable.spinaci)
 
 
    var focaccia_names: Array<String> = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.foaccia_titles)
    var focaccia_desc: Array<String> = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.foaccia_desc)
    val focaccia_price: IntArray = application.resources.getIntArray(R.array.foaccia_price)
    var focaccia_img: Array<Int> = arrayOf(R.drawable.base, R.drawable.nutella)
 
 
    var calzone_names: Array<String> = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.calzone_titles)
    var calzone_desc: Array<String> = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.calzone_desc)
    val calzone_price_normal: IntArray = application.resources.getIntArray(R.array.calzone_normal_price)
    val calzone_price_big: IntArray = application.resources.getIntArray(R.array.calzone_big_price)
    var calzone_img: Array<Int> = arrayOf(R.drawable.calzone)
 
 
    var panuozzo_names: Array<String> = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.panuozzo_titles)
    var panuozzo_desc: Array<String> = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.panuozzo_desc)
    val panuozzo_price_normal: IntArray = application.resources.getIntArray(R.array.panuozzo_normal_price)
    val panuozzo_price_big: IntArray = application.resources.getIntArray(R.array.panuozzo_big_price)
    var panuozzo_img: Array<Int> = arrayOf(R.drawable.panuozzo)
 
    val sosy_names: Array<String> = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.sosy_titles)
    val sosy_price: IntArray = application.resources.getIntArray(R.array.sosy_price)
 
    val napoje_names: Array<String> = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.napoje_titles)
    val napoje_price: IntArray = application.resources.getIntArray(R.array.napoje_price)
    val napoje_first_kind: Array<String> = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.napoje_kinds_one)
    val napoje_second_kind: Array<String> = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.napoje_kinds_two)
 
    val dodatki_names: Array<String> = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.dodatki_titles)
    val dodatki_small_price: IntArray = application.resources.getIntArray(R.array.dodatki_small_price)
    val dodatki_medium_price: IntArray = application.resources.getIntArray(R.array.dodatki_medium_price)
    val dodatki_big_price: IntArray = application.resources.getIntArray(R.array.dodatki_big_price)
 
    var list_of_addresses = ArrayList<Address>()
 
 
    private val mutableLoginStatus = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val loginStatus: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = mutableLoginStatus
 
    fun checkLogin(username: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
 
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
 
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username,password).addOnCompleteListener{
                    if(it.isSuccessful){
                        mutableLoginStatus.postValue(true)
                    }else{
                        mutableLoginStatus.postValue(false)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
 
 
 
    fun shareApp(context: Context) {
 
        val openURL = Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
 
        openURL.data = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/1488596184507308/")
        context.startActivity(openURL)
 
 
    }
 
 
 
 
    fun sendMail(context: Context) {
        val sendEmail = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        val email: Array<String> = arrayOf("kontakt@cilento.pl")
        sendEmail.setData(Uri.parse("mailto: kontakt@cilento.pl "))
        sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Problem z Usługą")
        sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Pizza którą zamówiłem nie przyszła na czas.\n\n\nMoje Dane Kontaktowe: \n\nImie: \nNazwisko: \nAdres: ")
        sendEmail.setType("message/rfc822")
        sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email)
        val chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendEmail, "Send mail using")
        context.startActivity(chooser)
    }
 
}
```

Address Class:

```
 package com.querto.model

 data class Address(
    val userId: String?,
     val name: String?,
    val street: String?,
      val postcode: String?,
    val house_number: String?,
     val city_name: String?
       )
```

Comment: I don't know kotlin, but usually i am able to understand what is going on, but it is too dificult with your code. First of all it is not a good idea to pass many different arrays to adapter instead of one. Then notifyDataSetChanged suppose to be called when data had just changed.

Comment: As I understand it, you call a new fragment when you want to add a new item? Where is the old data stored in this case?

Comment: in private fun addAddress you write - val addressAdapter= AddressAdapter. Does it mean you create new AddressAdapter? if yes it does not work like that

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain it here.
When you create a custom RecyclerView adapter usually you suppose to pass data you want to be displayed in the list. For me it is better to pass array Of Class You Made To Pass Data For Single Recylcer View item`ArrayList<ClassOfSingleItem>`, but it is not nessesary of course.
So when you call notifyDataSetCahnged you notify your adapter that data in this ArrayList was changed. But this call will not work if you create new Adapter every time you add or remove something from the RecyclerView list.

EDIT:
Let me explain what i see: you have button with click listener, when you click it you replace current fragmen with the one where you add data.

```
 view.add_address_btn.setOnClickListener {
             activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_in_anim, R.anim.fragment_fade_out_anim, R.anim.fragment_slide_out_anim, R.anim.fragment_fade_in_anim)?.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mMainActivityViewModel.addAddressFragment)?.commit()
            }
```

then, when you complete editing all fields what you do? replace your addAdressFragment with addressFragment:

```
val addressAdapter= AddressAdapter(requireContext(),  mMainActivityViewModel.list_of_addresses)
                    addressAdapter.addAddress(address)
                    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_in_anim, R.anim.fragment_fade_out_anim, R.anim.fragment_slide_out_anim, R.anim.fragment_fade_in_anim)?.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mMainActivityViewModel.addressFragment)?.commit()
```

inside this method you CREATE new AdressAdapter to call method addAdrees which has notifyDataSetChanged call inside. But recyclerView in your addressFragment has no idea about this new AddressAdapter. This is the main problem. As i mentioned in comment below my answer there are only two ways to update RecyclerView so implement one of them.
Below I show some java code (you mentioned you know java) which can give you an idea:

```
public class PointActivity extends BaseActivity  
       implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;  
@Override                                                            
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                              
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_point);                                                                         
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.point_list);                   
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    List<PointItem> pointItems = getFilteredAndSortedList();          
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new PointAdapter(this, pointItems));  
}   

//here we need to update recyclerView   
   @Override                                           
  public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {    
      searchResult(query);                            
      return false;                                   
 }                                                   
                                                      
public void searchResult(String query) {                                                                                               
    if (query.isEmpty()) {  
//just full list if query is empty                                                                                                           
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new PointAdapter(this, getFilteredAndSortedList()));                                                  
    } else {                                                                                                                           
        PointSearchManager pointSearchManager = new PointSearchManager();                                                              
        List<PointItem> list;                                                                                                          
        list = Arrays.asList(pointSearchManager.toFilters(getFilteredAndSortedList().toArray(new PointItem[0]), query)); 
//list filtered with query result              
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new PointAdapter(this, list));                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                  
}
```

Comment: Does this code in kotlin - val addressAdapter= AddressAdapter(requireContext... -  mean you create a new instance of AddressAdapter or not?

Comment: Is kotlin so different with other languages where keywords like val or var used to declare a variable?

Comment: i am sure that even if i made seprate class which will be displayed. it wont work

Comment: Read my answer again, please. There are two ways to update recyclerView. First - keep array of objects that contain data you want to display as local variable and call notifyDataSetChanged every time you add or remove object from array. Second - call recyclerView.setAdapter(new AddressAdapter(context, arrayListOfObjectsWithData))

Answer (score 0):

After Checking The MainActivityViewModel ,I See that you are not fetching data from the firebase database.
You should add this to AddressFragment class
also Add Variable called addressAdapter in the top of the class

```kotlin
fun getAddresses(){
   val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("addresses")
   ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                   val address = dataSnapshot.getValue<Address>()
                   mMainActivityViewModel.addresses_list.add(address)
                   addressAdapter.notifyDataChanged()
                } 
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
              
            }
        })

}
```

Also Implementing Address adapter  here does not do a thing . just remove it.

```kotlin
private fun addAddress(addressName: String, addressStreet: String, addressNumber: String,addressZipCode: String, addressCityName: String) {
    
            val address = Address(mAuth.currentUser?.uid, addressName, addressStreet,addressZipCode, addressNumber, addressCityName)
            database.child("addresses").child(database.push().key.toString()).setValue(address).addOnCompleteListener {
                if(it.isSuccessful){
                    val addressAdapter= AddressAdapter(requireContext(),  mMainActivityViewModel.address_title, mMainActivityViewModel.address_street,mMainActivityViewModel.address_post_code, mMainActivityViewModel.address_house_number, mMainActivityViewModel.address_city_name)
                    addressAdapter.addAddress(addressName, addressStreet,addressZipCode, addressNumber, addressCityName)
                    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_in_anim, R.anim.fragment_fade_out_anim, R.anim.fragment_slide_out_anim, R.anim.fragment_fade_in_anim)?.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mMainActivityViewModel.addressFragment)?.commit()
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Added address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Fail at creating address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you fetching Addresses from Firebase realtime Database?

Comment: You suppose to fetch the addresses from the database and add them to addresses array List in  mainViewModel

Comment: You are already saving the data in the firebase database .

Comment: you should call getAddresses() in onCreateView() , also there is no need for an adapter in addAddressFragment ,It has no purpose there. you already saved the address into the database .

Comment: my github with full code : https://github.com/polonez-byte-112/Querto

Comment: check here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#kotlin+ktx_4

Comment: Could we chat somewhere? Like whatsup or what convenient for u

Comment: i tried and it compiles but still nothing displayed unfortunatly. Thanks for help even it failed.I will push full code to github so u can try it.If it works for You , You can push to github as contributor :) .Thanks for help so much :)

Comment: You are welcome. just try to check firebase console and see if the data is being saved just in case.

Comment: i found bug but dont know how to fix this. i got this list of objects right? After adding up i tried to print size of this list and its always 0 .Something delete my object (again)

Comment: then define the list inside the address fragment rather than main Activity ViewModel

Comment: i pushed to github if you want to check.If you found solution u can push on github. Thanks for much after all  (Both guys) .You are angels :D